# Big Oh with log (n) and exponents

Tags: math, big-o

So I have a few given functions and need to fond Big Oh for them (which I did).

1. n log(n) =  O(n log(n))
2. n^2 = O(n^2)
3. n log(n^2) = O(n log(n))
4. n log(n)^2 = O(n^3)
5. n = O(n)

log is the natural logarithm.

I am pretty sure that 1,2,5 are correct.
For 3 I found a solution somewhere here: n log(n^2) = 2 n log (n) => O (n log n)
But I am completely unsure about 4). n^3 is definitely bigger than n*log(n^2) but is it the Oh of it? My other guess would be O(n^2).

A few other things:

- n^2 * log(n)
- n^2 * log(n)^2
  What would that be?

Would be great if someone could **explain** it if it is wrong. Thank you!

Comment: There's no such a thing as *the* O of a function; e.g. n = O(n³) as well as O(n²) and O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that big-O provides an asymptotic *upper bound* on a function, so any function that is O(n) is also O(n log n), O(n<sup>2</sup>), O(n!), etc.  Since log n = O(n), we have n log<sup>2</sup> n = O(n<sup>3</sup>).  It's also the case that n log<sup>2</sup> n = O(n log<sup>2</sup> n) and n log<sup>2</sup> n = O(n<sup>2</sup>).  In fact, n log<sup>2</sup> n = O(n<sup>1 + ε</sup>) for any ε > 0, since log<sup>k</sup> n = O(n<sup>ε</sup>) for any ε > 0.

The functions n<sup>2</sup> log n and n<sup>2</sup> log<sup>2</sup> n can't be simplified in the way that some of the other ones can.  Runtimes of the form O(n<sup>k</sup> log<sup>r</sup> n) aren't all that uncommon.  In fact, there are many algorithms that have runtime O(n<sup>2</sup> log n) and O(n<sup>2</sup> log<sup>2</sup> n), and these runtimes are often left as such.  For example, each iteration of the Karger-Stein algorithm takes time O(n<sup>2</sup> log n) because this runtime comes from the Master Theorem as applied to the recurrence

> T(n) = 2T(n / √2) + O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, maybe it should consider to change the question to: can n^2  log(n)^2 simplified. That was my biggest problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This answer has `log^2(n)=(log(n))^2`.  I think OP also was interested in `log(n^2)`, which is easily handled, since `log(n^2)=2log(n)`.

Comment: @Teepeemm- One of the OP's examples (number 3) uses log(n^2), but the rest used (log n)^2, which is what I focused on here.  You're absolutely right, though!